# Multitasking for a activity tracking app

Tags: ios, core-data, multitasking

I am building an activity tracking app. An app function is tracking time you spent for an activity. After user press a START button, I init a NSTimer, create an object in CoreData and change status of some buttons, labels...

The issue is how to restore app state after user press Home button. I can restore the app state, in case user reopen it from background mode without be terminated. But I can not restore in case it's terminated in background.

Can you guy advice me a solution for this issues? Whether I can keep the app does not be terminated or a better solution?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Doing this really well is a fairly long topic, but the concept is called [State Restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html). In its basic form (which is all you probably need), it's actually pretty simple and the system will do most of the work for you automatically if you ask for it. Some pointers:

- First, make sure you're not using the `NSTimer` to "count" time. That approach doesn't work. You can use an `NSTimer` to update the UI, but you should determine how much time has passed by subtracting the start time from the current time. Given that, you don't need to run in the background to track time passage.
- Since you're creating a Core Data object when the user presses start, a lot of the trouble is already taken care of for you. Just make sure you save before going into the background. When you come back, reload your current record.
- In your storyboard, give your view controllers a Storyboard and Restoration ID. This tells iOS that you would like it track these and restore them for you.

[image: Storyboard ID]

- Implement `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` and `decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` in your view controllers to keep track of what object you were working with. All of this is explained in the State Preservation and Restoration documentation linked above.